# Im trying to access a webpage which is online, but isnt responding in my browser

Tags: wordpress, web, proxy, cpanel

I was working on my website in wordpress, suddenly it stoped working on chrome, firefox, edge, when i troubleshoot it says: Resource is online but its not responding. (I tried to login on wordpress, cpanel but none of them works) I tried to fix proxy, reset network adapter, flush dns, most of the methods i have seen on youtube, but still isnt working.